# DirectX pure C: _IID_IDXGIDevice unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, directx, direct2d

I'm trying to set up the direct2d with direct3d device as Windows developer center tells me to. [How to create a Direct2D device context for rendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/hh780339(v=vs.85).aspx#how_to_create_a_direct2d_device_context_for_rendering)

At first I have to create a Direct3D Device. Done!
The next step is to get IDXGIDevice with QueryInterface() called on ID3D11Device. And that's a problem. I need to specify the IID for IDXGIDevice interface, but the symbol _IID_IDXGIDevice is unresolved. As I'm targeting the pure C, the __uuidof is not the option.

So, what should I do?

Comment: With such error (which is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966042/error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-iid-idirectdraw2), for example) you are supposed to link some additional library to satisfy linker. In your case it's dxguid.lib.

Comment: @RomanR. Yes, it is! You're the best!

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/issues/567#issuecomment-525846757), this case is by design, and @RomanR.'s comment is correct.